# How to make table columns not align?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table where columns in rows don't align with columns in other rows. Is it possible?

Comment: please elaborate more .. ..why are you thinking of using table then

Comment: either use colspan or just keep the cell empty , i dont know what exactly you trying to do.. just show something like what you want to create

Comment: you can use `colspan` effectively to make look and feel as you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is *no*.

However there are all kinds of possibilities:

1. Columns using `COLSPAN` so that they overlap with each other and sum in complex ways : there will still be inherent alignment but it can be complex.
2. Tables within tables - you can put a table inside a cell, and do it differently in the next row; these are now independent subtables and align independently.
3. Entirely separate tables one after another - just have 2 or more independent `<table>` blocks which align independently and use CSS to ensure that, for example, their total widths are the same or whatever constraint you want.

For recommendations on which suits you best we'd need to see what your actual desired layout looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can make adjustments using colspan or table within table would help. Or else try usi div instead its more flexible...